# la ejecución alcanzó el fin del procedimiento disparador sin encontrar RETURN

Tags: postgresql

tengo que crear un trigger PLPGSQL (`Update_detalles`) que comprueba la cantidad de la tabla(detalles pedidos), en función de las existencias que disponen la tabla (productos). Antes de realizar el update se comprueba si las existencias cubren el pedido, si el pedido excede las existencias el update cambia y se poco la existencias actuales como cantidad solicitada

el problema es problema esta en el `(if  exis < (new.cantidad))` que cuando el update activa ese if me da un error

> ERROR:  la ejecución alcanzó el fin del procedimiento disparador sin encontrar RETURN
> CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL update_detalles()
> función PL/pgSQL update_detalles() en la línea 11 en sentencia SQL
> SQL state: 2F005

```
create or replace function Update_detalles() returns trigger as $$
declare 
exis integer:=existencias from productos where id_producto=(select id_producto from detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido=(new.id_detalle_pedido));
Pa integer:= cantidad from detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido=(new.id_detalle_pedido);
begin

if     exis < (new.cantidad) then update productos set existencias=0
                                         where id_producto=(select id_producto from 
                                         detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido= 
                                         (new.id_detalle_pedido));
                                         
                                         update detalles_pedido set cantidad=exis where 
                                         id_detalle_pedido=(new.id_detalle_pedido)
                            
elseif exis > (new.cantidad) then update productos set existencias=((exis + pa) - new.cantidad) 
                                         where id_producto=(select id_producto from 
                                         detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido= 
                                         (new.id_detalle_pedido)); 
                                        
                                         return new;
end if;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Quizás sea que le falta el punto y coma antes del elseif.

Comment: Si tiene el ( ; ), solo que cuando realice la pregunto no lo coloque, pero si esta en el código original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice el error te esta faltando un RETURN, por ende debes poner un `RETURN` también en la primera parte dl `IF` y no solo en el `elseif`, o de lo contrario debes ponerlo al final siempre. Las funciones trigger siempre tienen que tener un `RETURN` para finalizar.

```
declare 
exis integer:=existencias from productos where id_producto=(select id_producto from detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido=(new.id_detalle_pedido));
Pa integer:= cantidad from detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido=(new.id_detalle_pedido);
begin

if     exis < (new.cantidad) then update productos set existencias=0
                                         where id_producto=(select id_producto from 
                                         detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido= 
                                         (new.id_detalle_pedido));
                                         
                                         update detalles_pedido set cantidad=exis where 
                                         id_detalle_pedido=(new.id_detalle_pedido);
               return new;
                            
elseif exis > (new.cantidad) then update productos set existencias=((exis + pa) - new.cantidad) 
                                         where id_producto=(select id_producto from 
                                         detalles_pedido where id_detalle_pedido= 
                                         (new.id_detalle_pedido)); 
                                        
                                         return new;
end if;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: o retornar el new por fuera del if-else como pa simplificar :P

Comment: Al añadir el return new; en el if, cuando ejecuto el update, que dispara el trigger no me da error pero no me da el resultado espero, ya que el return new, ejecuta el update, pero pero se supone que el disipador en el paso del if anula el update y ejecuta otra acción en su lugar!

Comment: entonces es un tema lógica de tu escenario, debes decidir si es RETRUN NEW, RETURN OLD o RETURN NULL, en este caso debe ser RETURN NULL ;-)

Comment: Si cologo RETURN NULL; no ejecuta el comando del IF, no coloco RETURN NEW, ejecuta la acción del update, pero se supone que el trigger tiene que detectar que no se puede y hace otra acción en su lugar, y el RETUR OLD, me da error

Comment: Entonces debes revisar tu logica de negocio del codigo